# Is it possible to change P4TICKET within P4Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, perforce, p4eclipse

I installed Eclipse Juno recently and after it I installed the p4Eclipse 4.2 plugin from this repository: 
http://www.perforce.com/downloads/http/p4-eclipse/install/4.2

Then I tried to create a new perforce connection.I entered the name of server and username and password. But I got an error message when clicking on next:

**com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConfigException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \p4tickets.txt (Access is denied)**

Reading the P4Eclipse help I understood that because I didn't define the user environment variable P4TICKETS the P4Eclipse tried to define it by itself. On the help has mentioned that if the value is not explicitly is set it will be defined for windows as %USERPROFILE%\p4tickets.txt
and for all other platforms as
$HOME/.p4tickets

It seems that P4Eclipse has configured for other platforms and therefore it tried to find the file somewhere which it was not allowed. When I defined the User Environment variable P4TICKETS with the value %USERPROFILE%\p4tickets.txt it worked. The problem is that we have many clients and I don't want to define an environment variable for all of them. So I wonder if there is a set to configure P4Eclipse for Windows platform or define the P4TICKETS within eclipse and not with an environment variable!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can go to the advanced configuration for the plugin and set P4TICKETS.  In the release notes they describe this method for setting P4HOST:

## 470897 (Bug #042451)

```
    Support for P4HOST variable. To set P4HOST variable, 
    either set the environment variable P4HOST (For example,
    export P4HOST=123.456.789.0) or in the the preference page, 
    Preference>Team>Perforce>Advanced, set P4HOST properties,
    (For example, name: P4HOST value: 123.456.789.0). Then
    restart Eclipse to make it affect.
```

I'm not 100% sure that will work but you can give it a try.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I tested it actually before asking. I tested it actually before asking. I am getting the same error pointing to User_home folder despite what I am entering as parameter in the advanced perforce preferences. But Thank you!